# Getting +/- voltage from a benchtop power supply

Tags: power-supply, ground

I have this benchtop PSU which I got from some dude on Craigslist:

[image]

I need to power a circuit that requires +12v, -12v, and a ground reference. Currently the way I do it is to use one channel of the power supply to provide 24v, and use a simple voltage divider on a breadboard to provide a fake ground. But that is not a very good long-term solution.

I figured I could get a -12v out of the second PSU channel by just hooking up + and - backwards. Would that work? How would I make a ground in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your power supply unit contains 2 independent power supplies.  Each one has a ground, + and - terminals.  To get +12 volts from one, connect the ground and - terminals together and then hook the + terminal to where your circuit needs +12 volts and hook the - terminal to where your circuit needs the +12 volt return.  On the 2nd power supply on your unit, connect the ground terminal to the + terminal.  Now connect the - terminal to where your circuit needs -12 volts and hook the + terminal to where your circuit needs the -12 volt return. If you set your supply unit to the master/slave mode, then you need only adjust the master supply to 12 volts and the other (slave) supply will automatically follow.  Otherwise, you can set them separately if you prefer.

Comment: Why not use the "series" setting to put the two supplies in series, tap out of the middle for ground and use one as + and the other as - ?

Comment: @Bob, good idea. I'll try that this evening; probably easier to set up. There's no particular reason why this circuit needs to be tied to the real ground, but either way should work.